# Trying to create a local repo of go.tools that is go get-able

Tags: git, go, bitbucket-server

I have added a new switch (-xml) to the go cover tool to generate an XML doc that is consumable by Atlassian clover so the bamboo builds of our go projects can report simple coverage statistics.  I would like this local version to be accessible to the build agents using go get <importpath>.

These are the steps I've tried:

```
- setup $GOPATH
- created $GOPATH/src/stash.example.com/scm/x
- cd $GOPATH/src/stash.example.com/scm/x
- git clone --bare https://go.goolesource.com/tools
```

and then basically followed the steps for importing an existing git project into stash as described in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-ImportanexistingGitprojectintoStash

If I then 'rm -rf tools' followed by 'go get -d stash.example.com/scm/x/tools' I get "unrecognized import path stash.example.com/scm/x/tools".  It works if I type 'go get -d stash.example.com/scm/x/tools.git' (providing the vcs hint to go get), but the resulting subdirectory is named 'test.git'.  The alternative to providing the vcs hint in the path is to return a <meta> tag in the html from the stash server, but I have no idea how to create that.

I should add that 'cd $GOPATH/src/stash.example.com/scm/x' + 'git clone http://user@stash.example.com/scm/x/tools.git' creates the tools subdirectory as expected.

I must host this on a local server inside my firewall, so github is not an option.  Any advice?

Comment: The tools that install into GOROOT are hard-coded into the `go` tool. You can't change their import path, or they won't install into the correct location.

Comment: This is relatively true.  After fixing up the import paths in the tool component files with the local path, the tool builds fine.  go install places the result in $GOPATH/bin, but moving it to $GOTOOLDIR is a simple matter.  At that point, the new 'go tool cover -xml=coverage.out' behavior works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

What does `curl http://stash.example.com/scm/x/tools` yield? What servers are listening on `stash.example.com`? Generally, a `go get`-able path either contains a component with a suffix denoting the revision control system used (e.g. `example.com/repository.git/package`) or a certain meta-tag exists in one of the directory layers that tells `go get` where to get the source.

`go get` is an unsophisticated mechanism and if I recall correctly it doesn't work with git when the server requires authentication.

Have a look [here](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) for the relevant documentation on how import paths work with `go get`. I'm not going to cite out of this as it's rather long, unlikely to go down and you can retrieve it on your local machine by installing `godoc` and running

```
godoc -http=:8080 # or some other port
```

and then pointing your browser to

```
http://localhost:8080/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  If I get the repo with curl I get "Invalid request from host 192.168.1.111: Note that Stash does not support Git's legacy HTTP transport protocol."  So I guess stash is looking at user-agent or something. I looked at the link you cited and it seems to come down to returning a meta tag from stash for a custom import path, but I have no idea how to do this.  Here's someone trying to accomplish the same thing: [link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/329277/making-git-suffix-for-repository-urls-optional)

Comment: @kerlyn Try to put the repo in an URL that contains the suffix `.git` in the directory where the git repository is found. For instance, if the repo is `git:example.com/foo.git`, try an import path like `example.com/foo.git/package`.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I still end up with ".git" in the pathname.  Not elegant, but also not fatal.  As I say above, the import paths have to be fixed in the tool component files and the resulting binary moved to the correct location, but the end result works as desired.

Comment: @kerlyn If you don't want the import-path to contain `.git`, an HTTP server needs to serve the page at the import path. This page needs to contain a certain meta-tag (described above) that points to the path where the package is located.

Comment: Agreed, so the question is whether such a meta tag can be returned by stash as per the [link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/329277/making-git-suffix-for-repository-urls-optional) I posted above.